# Changing Keyboard Shortcuts for all users (/skel)?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I am looking for a way to change the default keyboard combination for changing the input language (in System Settings, Text Entry: `Switch to next source:`) for each new user created on a freshly installed Ubuntu.

The default key combination is ALT+Space, and I'd like it to be the Left ALT+Shift.